# I need to order the columns of the joined table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have many-to-many relationship table and i having the query like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT vp.quotes 
from VehiclePlan as vp 
LEFT JOIN vp.quotes q 
LEFT JOIN q.customer c 
WHERE (1=1) AND vp.date=(:date) AND vp.vehicleId=(:vehicleId)  
ORDER BY q.collectionDateTime
```

But still my data are not coming in ordered form.PLease help me out with this.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What order do you mean? Since you're only selecting `vp.quotes` (which would be `q` as per your join)  you'd get whatever entity a quote represents and there is no "column" order in entities.

Comment: Btw, what purpose do `(1=1)` and joining customers have?

Comment: if i have no filters then this will return 1=1 data. and customer is for my internal purpose. Here i have 3 field of quotes in which i want to apply sorting. I m selecting the quotes and it should be ordered as per the given q.collectionDateTime

Comment: Hmm, if there are no other filters you could entirely skip the where clause but ok, that's your choice of style. As for your problem: please enhance your question with some example of what you'd expect and what you get instead. The query you posted should work as intended.